# EditText value cannot update in alertdialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, dialog

I'm trying to add `editText` in the pop-up dialog for users to write notes/task but the value in `editText` cannot be saved after clicking "add" button, the message did not show on the `ListView`. Here's the code:

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listView;
    public static ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<>();
    public static CustomAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private CheckBox checkBox;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences
                        ("com.example.assignment2", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>)
                sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

        if (set == null) {

            notes.add("Empty");

        } else {

            notes = new ArrayList(set);

        }

        arrayAdapter = new CustomAdapter
                (this, R.layout.simplerow, notes);

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
               AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Add Task")
                    .setMessage("Enter Message")
                    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_add)
                    .setView(input)
                    .setPositiveButton("Add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                      String task = input.getText().toString();
                      notes.add(task);
                        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                                getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences
                                        ("com.example.assignment2",
                                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

              HashSet<String> set = new HashSet(notes);

              sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).commit();
                    }
                })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                        .create();
                ad.show();
            }

            });
```

the dialog looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQcsz.png).
I was expecting the message will be saved and display it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzJLx.png)  after clicking "add" button
Anyone willing to help? :(
**notes** is an **ArrayList**.

Comment: What do you mean cannot be saved? How do you know it's not working? Try changing the "apply()" call on the SharedPreferences Editor to "commit()".

Comment: I tried entering some text in it but it appeared nothing after clicking the "add" button. It did not display the text message I'd written.

Comment: By default, the AlertDialog API dismisses once a button is clicked. Is that what you mean? When you select "add" the dialog disappears from the screen?

Comment: No the text message is supposed to save in arraylist and display it in textview after clicking "add" button.

Comment: You aren't updating a TextView in the onClick callback so that's why you're not seeing the result. I see that you are saving it into an ArrayList and telling a list adapter that it's dataset has changed but is the "notes" ArrayList the dataset for the list adapter? If not, your list never changes because it doesn't know of the new data. Could you post more of the code, such as the construction of the list and adapter?

Comment: I'd updated the code. Yes "notes" ArrayList is for the list adapter.

Comment: What exactly happens when you select add?

Comment: Uploaded an image might be easier to understand

Comment: Interesting, so it looks to be adding an item when you press the add button you just can't see the text. My two suggestions would be to debug and make sure " input.getText().toString()" is actually returning a value, also make sure the text color of your list item view isn't white. A simple mistake, but an easy one to overlook in a rush.

Comment: returning value like ```TextView.setText(task);```?

Comment: What is the value of task? Is it an empty string or null?

Comment: I added that code in but it said null object reference :(

Answer (score 0):

Move this Lines of ode in onCreate method of Activity.

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
```

In onCreate

```
sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext()
                              .getSharedPreferences("com.example.assignment2",
                                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```